# Публикация веб-сервиса на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-служба

**Добрый день!**

Столкнулся с интересной задачей - я написал веб-сервис, у тебя на машине его протестировал, теперь хочу выложить на сервер.

Я ни разу этого не делал, поэтому хочу **проконсультироваться**. Как я понимаю, нужно в IIS **создать папку**, назвать, например "TestService", положить туда файл веб-сервиса, дать права на **чтение**. В результате чего получится, как мне кажется, URL к нашему в.сервису.

Вопросы:

1. Все ли я указал правильно, или возможно нужно еще что-то сделать, чтобы можно было позже использовать в.сервис?
2. Если бы веб-сервис был в папке с Решением, можно было бы использовать его [так](http://sarangasl.blogspot.ru/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html). Теперь же, когда он на сервере, мы должны  сформировать СОАП-сообщение и через HttpWebRequest его отправить на сервер по URL на веб-сервис. Возможно, этот путь можно упростить, и как-то добавить ссылку на веб-сервис на сервере?

Comment: Вроде всё правильно. Иногда делаю для веб-сервиса отдельный "сайт" в IIS, иногда создаю его в рамках какого-то другого сайта в отдельной папке. Тут есть еще вопрос безопасности. Нужно ли чтобы к сервису имели доступ сторонние пользователи или сервис для внутреннего использования, например, для другого веб-приложения?

Answer (score 3):

По поводу публикации. В целом все верно. Но один одинокий файл веб-сервиса может и не заработать (а может и заработать, зависит от разных факторов).

Обычно необходимы следующие файлы:

- сам веб-сервис (вы используете `*.asmx`, правильно?);
- либо файл с кодом к нему, если вы используете codebehind - либо dll с базовым классом в папке bin, если вы используете наследование;
- файл `web.config`.

Но можно немного упростить процесс сбора файлов - выполните команду `(путь к msbuild.exe) /t Package /p Configuration=Release` в папке вашего проекта. Вы получите пакет, который можно развернуть на веб-сервере через службу `msdeploy`.

Или, если вы не хотите использовать `msdeploy` - используйте команду `(путь к msbuild.exe) /t PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeploy /p Configuration=Release /p WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder=(путь к выходной папке)` - это скопирует все необходимые файлы из вашего проекта в по указанному пути. Или можно выполнить первую команду, после чего заглянуть в `obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp`.

Еще есть вариант публикации проекта из студии - он делает примерно то же самое, можно публиковать проект как сразу на сервер - так и в выходную папку.

Теперь ответ на второй вопрос. Разумеется, всегда можно послать сообщение `SOAP` через `HTTP` самостоятельно. Но обычно так не делают - ведь есть способ проще. Правильно настроенный веб-сервис должен уметь отдавать описание своего интерфейса в формате `WSDL`. Обычно для этого надо добавить к его адресу в конец суффикс `?wsdl`.

Такое описание может быть использовано для автоматической генерации клиента, который возьмет на себя формирование сообщения SOAP, отправку запроса и разбор ответа. В английской версии Студии это делается через пункт контекстного меню проекта "Add Service Reference". Также есть консольная утилита `wsdl.exe`, которая делает то же самое.